# Как удалить пустое значение в фрейме данных?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

У меня есть фрейм данных [airline_passengers](https://github.com/Alex-zlat/Kazantcev_DS-25/blob/master/MACHINE_LEARNING/TIME_SERIES/1_Introduction_to_time_series/international-airline-passengers.csv).

В датасете есть одно пустое значение.

Инициализируем переменную с данными:

```
airline_passengers = pd.read_csv('international-airline-passengers.csv')`.
```

Пытаюсь удалить из переменной пустое значение:

```
airline_passengers = airline_passengers[~np.isnan(airline_passengers)]`
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ufunc "isnan"не поддерживается для типов входных данных, и входные
> данные не могут быть безопасно принудительно привязаны к любым
> поддерживаемым типам в соответствии с правилом приведения "безопасно"

Почему так? Чуть далее в коде я тем же способом переназначения переменной удалил пустое значение:

```
series = boxcox(all_series['International airline passengers: monthly totals in thousands'], 0)
series = series[~np.isnan(series)] # удалим единственное значение Nan из массива
```

Здесь `all_series` — словарь различных датасетов (вернее, извлеченных из них Series):

```
all_series = {
    "Monthly sales of company in january": sales_of_company_jan['Count'],
    "Monthly sales of company in 1960": sales_of_company_1960['Count'],
    "International airline passengers: monthly totals in thousands": airline_passengers['International airline passengers: monthly totals in thousands. Jan 49 ? Dec 60']
}
```

Comment: А о каком пустом значении идет речь? у меня датафрейм читается без "прустых" значений, все 144 строки.

Comment: Я вижу один NaN:
`airline_passengers.isnull().values.sum()`

# 1

Comment: В таком случае вы пользуетесь неверным инструментарием. вы получаете не массив какой-то, а датафрейм, у него такой набор инструментов, закачаешься. поэтому вам нужно немного разобраться в pandas  и использовать в таком случае метод `dropna`, как и показал в своем ответе MaxU

Comment: и, кстати, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: dropna() оказался на высоте - все гениальное просто )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alex-zlat/Kazantcev_DS-25/master/MACHINE_LEARNING/TIME_SERIES/1_Introduction_to_time_series/international-airline-passengers.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=1, header=None, names=["Month", "Val"]).dropna()
```

результат:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
       Month    Val
0    1949-01  112.0
1    1949-02  118.0
2    1949-03  132.0
3    1949-04  129.0
4    1949-05  121.0
..       ...    ...
139  1960-08  606.0
140  1960-09  508.0
141  1960-10  461.0
142  1960-11  390.0
143  1960-12  432.0

[144 rows x 2 columns]

In [16]: df.dtypes
Out[16]:
Month     object
Val      float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: помогло. dropna() отработал. Не пришлось добавлять оставшиеся параметры метода pd.read_csv(), но последовавший в заключение работ тест Дики-Фуллера на стационарность нормализованного ряда пройден успешно!